# Why do certain programs not play well when piped into `more`

Tags: bash

Why does `| more` take no effect for some programs, when run in bash?

I get that behavior with `leiningen`, not really a command but a program. I think indeed it happens in cases where the output is sent to stderr. I'll be confirming that.

Comment: An example of such a command, perhaps?

Comment: Most likely because said commands don't send their output to `stdout`.

Comment: I get that behavior with [leiningen](http://leiningen.org/), not really a command but a program. I think indeed it happens in cases where the output it sent to stderr. I'll be confirming that.

Comment: Theoretically a program could also check what pipe stdout points to and then depending on this misbehave but I don't you would be coming across such a case in the real world.

Answer (score 5):

The pipe symbol ("`|`") connects the `STDOUT` stream from the left side process to the `STDIN` stream of the right side process. It sounds like your program is outputting to `STDERR`.

You can send `STDERR` to `STDOUT`, and both to the pipe via:

```
program 2>&1 | more
```

Comment: Since this is bash, there is a shortcut. You can replace `2>&1 |` with `|&`.